# UiPath Selector not working in `Type Into` Activity

Tags: rpa, uipath

I'm new to UiPath and I'm following all the tutorials available in their website, Planning also to finish the **`Foundation Training`**
but I'm confused why **`Type info Activity`** doesn't seem to work.

I used the `Launch UI Explorer` then select the Target Element and Relative Element in web. I removed the `Id attribute` since it has a dynamic value then copy the *`selector value`* that was generated.

[image]

 Paste the value in the Selector Editor in `Type into Activity` then it shows error, it doesn't seem to work at all.

[image]

Please help me to resolve this problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @YouCrackedMeUp are you developing or extending existing functionality in UIPath? I'm developing new RPA tool just like UiPath but lack knowledge on tools and API's, do you know any ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now I figured it out how to resolve this problem.

I only added **`double quote`** in selector value in `Type into` selector editor. I was confused at first because in the video tutorial they have different selector editor view, compared to what I'm currently using, so that's why during I paste the value, it did not treated as string on my end. below screenshot is the `selector editor` view in tutorial.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I actually saw this too during I'm taking the `Foundation Training`. You must add
double quote (" ") on your selector value to make this work. Thanks